# Grunt-SSH error: Malformed cygwin unix socket file

Tags: javascript, windows, ssh, gruntjs, git-bash

I am trying to set up a [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) task to ssh into a remote server and perform some operations using [grunt-ssh](https://github.com/chuckmo/grunt-ssh). I am using git bash on a windows machine. The relevant parts of my Gruntfile.js are the following:

```
grunt.initConfig({
sshconfig: {
    portfolioServer: {
    host: 'myWebsite.com',
    username: 'root',
    agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
    }
},

sshexec:{
    deploy:{
    command: [
        'cd portfolio',
        'git pull'
    ].join(' && ')
    },
    options:{
    config: 'portfolioServer'
    }
},


........etc.

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ssh');
```

My problem is that when I run my `grunt deploy` task, i get the following error:

```
Running "sshexec:deploy" (sshexec) task
Warning: Connection :: error :: Error: Malformed cygwin unix socket file Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

If I then run using the `--force` flag, I get the following output:

```
Running "sshexec:deploy" (sshexec) task
Warning: Connection :: error :: Error: Malformed cygwin unix socket file Used --force, continuing.
Warning: Connection :: error :: Error: Authentication failure. Available authentication methods: publickey,password Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.
```

This seems to suggest I have either set up my SSH authentication incorrectly, or that the commands I have used to get the command line to recognize my keys are poorly formed. This confuses me a little, as I have followed the instructions [here](http://anterence.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/ssh-agent-in-msysgit.html) to set up SSH keys on the command line, and am able to successfully ssh into my server by typing `ssh root@myWebsite.com`

What is going wrong?

Comment: Did you come across a solution to this?

Comment: I just tried connecting with an ssh-agent under Cygwin 2.0.0 and after fixing a bug (unrelated to yours) that had to do with getting the right socket path, I was able to connect just fine. If you are still encountering this problem and you get a chance, please post the contents of the file at `process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.